# Make taxvat not required on customer registration form programmatically

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation

I want to force taxvat field as not required on customer create form
Even if i have ovrride

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/taxvat.phtml

with a plugin in my custom module

```
<div class="field taxvat">
<label class="label" for="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('taxvat')) ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getStoreLabel('taxvat')) ?></span></label>
<div class="control">
    <input type="text" id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldId('taxvat')) ?>" name="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFieldName('taxvat')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getTaxvat()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStoreLabel('taxvat')) ?>" class="input-text ">
</div>
```

removing data-validate="{required:true}"

when i submit form it get me error "Tax/VAT Number" is a required value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That should be manageable from admin. Location:

**Stores -> Configuration -> Customer -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Address Options**

[image]

Comment: yes off course but i need a programmatically way :(

Answer (score 0):

solution is to override validateValue function in class

> \Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Text